# Using input parameters for validation with marshmallow

Tags: python, marshmallow

Is it possible to pass parameters to a marshmallow schema to use for validation on load?

I have the following schema:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate

class ExampleSchema(Schema):
    tags = fields.List(fields.String(), validate=ContainsOnly(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

and I'm wondering whether, instead of typing `"a", "b", "c"`, I could put parameters in there? Something like

```
class ExampleSchema(Schema, list_of_allowed_tags):
    tags = fields.List(fields.String(), validate=ContainsOnly(list_of_allowed_tags))
```

except this doesn't work because the following error comes up on import

```
NameError: name 'list_of_allowed_tags' is not defined
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: you cann't inhert the `list_of_allowed_tag` in the class, but you can pass function which return the allowed list guess

Comment: @sahasrara62 Pass a function instead of the array when I initialize the class? Or create a class method that somehow does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, marshmallow Schema doesn't do that.

You can use a schema factory.

```
import marshmallow as ma


def example_schema_factory(list_of_allowed_tags):

    class ExampleSchema(ma.Schema):
        tags = ma.fields.List(
            ma.fields.String(),
            validate=ma.validate.ContainsOnly(list_of_allowed_tags)
        )

    return ExampleSchema
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below link for the answer:

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_fields.html#adding-context-to-method-and-function-fields